# calculate month and day using millisecond in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i want to calculate the remaining month and days by using the millisecond..

the below code ..i calculate the number of year when user enter the birth date but how can i calculate remaining month and days.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>A Web Page</h1>
<input type="text "id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
 var a=document.getElementById("demo").value;
 var birthdate = new Date(a);
 var cur = new Date();
 var diff = cur-birthdate; // This is the difference in milliseconds
 var age = Math.floor(diff/31557600000); // Divide by 1000*60*60*24*365.25
     var month=;//i want to calcuate this using millsecond only
     var days=;//i want to calcuate this using millsecond only


 alert("Hi ..you are "+ age+"and"+month+"and"+days+" year old Now");
}
</script>
```

help mi thanks..

Comment: If you're planning to do more date/time stuff in JavaScript, I'd have a look at [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)!

Answer (score 0):

Months and dys are calculated from the remainder of the division

```
var remainder = diff % 31557600000;
var month = Math.floor(remainder / (1000*60*60*24*30.5));
var remainder2 = remainder % (1000*60*60*24*30.5);
var days = Math.floor(remainder2 / (1000*60*60*24));
```

Comment: Does this solution, take leap year into consideration?

Comment: @Yasser no, it does not, it does not evaluate the number of days in different months, if one needs to take these into account, there are different libraries that can be used. For a quick calculation though, I use them as approximations

Comment: What's with people downvoting with no comments these days. Upvoted to neutralise.

Comment: Thanks @Yasser, most probably it is not the perfect solution